# cache provider for hibernate + jsf + spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jsf, caching

Which cache provider is suggested for an application that uses

- Hibernate3
- Spring
- JSF2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EHCache](http://ehcache.org/) (originally "Easy Hibernate Cache") has been used in Hibernate for a long time, so it's the first choice.

Comment: I would doubt it, since it has been bought by Teracotta - a VM clustering solution :)

Comment: See here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache

it seems that it doesn't support clustering in Hibernate

Comment: on the other hand i see here:
http://relation.to/Bloggers/Ehcache20SupportsNewHibernate33CachingProvider
that it supports clustering. So what do you say?

Answer (score 2):

[EhCache](http://ehcache.org/) is the obvious choice. Unless you have a reason to pick something else, then pick that one.